# NumberLong arithmetic in the Mongo shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How can I perform precise arithmetic on NumberLong values in the Mongo shell?  It's my understanding that Javascript only has one numeric type - `number` - typically limited to 54-bit floating-point precision.

Direct arithmetic using (e.g.) standard addition shows demoting coercion to lower-precision type:

```
> NumberLong("123456789012345678")+NumberLong("1") 
123456789012345680
> NumberLong("123456789012345678")+NumberLong("2")
123456789012345680
```

I can see how to extract portions of a NumberLong using string representations, but this seems inefficient and is not useful for such arithmetic operations as increment or divide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB uses the [BSON 64 bit Int type](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) ([Mongo type code 18](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24type)) for NumberLong. The db kernel can perform precise arithmetic on these elements (kernel written in C++) through doing update operations but if you want to do this in the javascript shell you'll need a library like [this one](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_math_long.js.html) from Google.

Comment: the other piece of the puzzle is getting the top/bottom 32 bits, which appear to be private (see JIRA [SERVER-4141](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4141)).  i should be able to proceed from here - thanks!

Comment: It really su**s those arithmetic operations aren't exposed. It makes M/R jobs dealing with NumberLong such an hassle...

Comment: @jpredham What is the library for that NumberLong arithmetics? Your link is broken!

Comment: @HamidAlaei Looks like Google moved the closure library to github: https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.math.Long.html. However, this answer is now over 6 years old and I'm not sure if it's still relevant.