# How do I perform integer arithmetic in mongodb shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Is there any way to perform integer arithmetic on two NumberInt or NumberLongs in MongoDB's mapreduce Javascript or in the shell?  As you see, I get:

```
> typeof (NumberInt(1) + NumberInt(1))
number

# (and this is here sort of just to gripe)
> NumberLong(2) == NumberInt(2)
false
> 2==NumberLong(2)
true
> 2==NumberInt(2)
true
```

Relevant:

- [mongo db map reduce sum results as integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817598/mongo-db-map-reduce-sum-results-as-integer) seems to be the same, but I get different results.
- [NumberLong arithmetic in the Mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592825/numberlong-arithmetic-in-the-mongo-shell) is far from trivial to actually do.

Comment: typeof is not arithmetic

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  `1+1` is the arithmetic.  `typeof` just shows us that the returned value is `number` and not `NumberInt`.

Comment: I have been looking around a bit and even converting to native JS isn't a good way to go since you can loose precision on big ints, not sure how much of a choice you have in JS alone

Comment: look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592825/numberlong-arithmetic-in-the-mongo-shell

Answer (score 1):

Since these are actually objects, use their methods:

```js
var num1 = NumberLong(2);
var num2 = NumberInt(2);

num1.toNumber() == num2.toNumber()
```

Which will return `true`. And in the same way:

```js
var num1 = NumberLong(2);
var num2 = NumberInt(3);

num1.toNumber() == num2.toNumber()
```

Returns `false` as they are not equal:

```js
num1.toNumber() < num2.toNumber()
```

Is also valid as `true`

So you basically need to use the method to do the casting in this way.

Comment: That does not solve the arithmetic issue. I still cannot do integer-space arithmetic.

Comment: @ScottStafford Not sure what you are talking about as your question does not even make this point clear. Perhaps expand on what you wish to do. If you are talking about "adding" the value of a "Long" to an "Int" then if you **tried** this with the methods I used then you would see that it works.

Comment: Yes, `NumberLong(2).toNumber() + NumberInt(2).toNumber()` will result in 4.  But the Javascript `number` is a double.  So if you try doing the same thing with very large integers it will start rounding them.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t for instance.  My question is about getting mongo db to integer arithmetic, which will not round, instead of floating-point arithmetic.